# History.js - prevent updating hashes

Tags: javascript, url, history.js

I'd love to use History.js for its ability to handle history (pushState etc.) in older browsers but I'd need to disable the default behavior that automatically converts hashes into a "normal" url path.
By that I mean that by default the script changes link#hash to link/hash. It is great that if a push a state of "otherlink", it gives older browsers the #otherlink hash so it can still be handled but I need it to NOT automatically change link#hash to link/hash when the page is loaded. History.js seems to include an auto-initialize code so I don't even know how to load it with customized options.

To be specific, what I need is:

- A page link#hash will remain link#hash
- History.pushState (..., "#hash") will push the state but the page will be page#hash not page/hash
- History.pushState (..., "hash") will be page/hash in modern browsers but page#hash in older browsers (and the script will handle what needs to be handled to load proper content).

I hope it makes sense. If it doesn't I can provide more information.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21673425/2903169

Quoted from previous answer I gave earlier today (retaining the hash in history.js seems to be a popular question)

> Within the History.js github repo, you can set the options to force
>   hashtags as Default
>
> [History.js Github Readme, Options Link](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/#options)
>
> History.options.html4Mode   If true, will force HTMl4 mode (hashtags)