# Stop History.js from changing the address URL

Tags: javascript, url, history.js

I've been experimenting with History.js lately (https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/). I notice when you use the History.pushState(), History.js removes everything upto the first / and replaces that with the hash.

I.E. current url: www.google.com/something

```
History.pushState({},null,"something2");
```

sets the address bar to www.google.com/something2

whereas in HTML4 it would use the hash (#) -> www.google.com/something#something2

Is there anyway to disable this feature. I'l like it to not remove everything up to the '/', but without necessarily going back to HTML4. I know there's a History.options.html4Mode, but I still like how it stores the index internally, as opposed to using the suid.

Comment: Can you clarify what you would like to have instead? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: History.js clears everything uptill the first / in the current url, like in my example, it cleared something and replaced it with the hash I'm pushing. I'd like it to not clear anything and preferably just do what it did back in html4, add the hash to the end of the url after a '#', like www.google.com/somethng#something2.

Answer (score 0):

Within the History.js github repo, you can set the options to force hashtags as Default

[History.js Github Readme, Options Link](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/#options)

> ```
> History.options.html4Mode
> ```
>
> If true, will force HTMl4 mode (hashtags)